# How to find last modification in database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an application which stores all data in SQL Server 2008. This application creates, modifies, updates tables. The name of the database is `XLPR_2001` and it contains nearly 500 tables.

I want to find out changes if I made through application where it affect the entire database (`XLPR_2001`). If I find it so I can directly made those changes directly in the database, I complete my work very fast.

I search it on web but not help me in my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@sarslash and  @Yogesh in my case your code show very old result. I found below code on somewhere and it work perfectly.

```
select
    object_name(object_id) as OBJ_NAME, *
from
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
where
    database_id = db_id(db_name())
Order by
    dm_db_index_usage_stats.last_user_update desc
```

Answer (score 7):

As your Question, you are looking for Table Change Effect :

```
SELECT name [TableName],
       Create_date [CreateDate],
       modify_date [LastUpdate]
FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE type = 'U'
ORDER BY modify_date DESC;
```

From above `SQL` Command which would give you all `Table_Name` which are last effected by some activities (i.e. insert, update or delete).

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: perfect, exactly what I needed! Thank you so much

Comment: The information above that it updates for insert, update or delete  is incorrect - this only captures changes to table structure (DDL) , not data itself (DML).

Answer (score 2):

You can find this info at modify_date column of sys.objects table

```
SELECT name, modify_date from sys.objects where type ='U' order by modify_date desc
```

Comment: your query show me modified date very old, I am looking for just last changes in database with table name.

Comment: i changed the query